# How is it possible to change a matrix in Julia?

Tags: julia

Would you please help me? 
I have this matrix

```
> rout
4×5 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  1  4  0  2
 0  3  0  1  2
 0  2  4  0  3
 0  1  4  2  3
```

each row of this matrix has some sections. for example first row has two sections. section one includes 1,4 and section two includes 2 and last row has one section 1,2,3,4. I want to get a matrix which the number of sections in each row seat as value of another matrix (`nrout[i,j]`). 
for before `rout` matrix, this `nrout` can be made:(columns of `nrout` are 1,2,3,4)

```
> nrout
4×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  0  1
 2  2  1  0
 0  1  2  1
 1  1  1  1
```

instead 1 in  `rout` seats 1 (the number of section 1) in  `nrout`. instead 4 puts 1(the number of section 1) in  `nrout`. instead 2 puts 2 (the number of section 2) in  `nrout`.

would you pleas help me that how this matrix can be made in Julia?

Comment: I removed the "jump" tag, since this is not specifically about JUMP (unless you explain why exactly). Also, what you're asking is unclear to me; can you explain a bit more how the other rows of `nrout` relate to `rout`? Then we would have more examples.

Comment: Thanks. Nods appeared in rout {1,2,3,4} make columns of nrout respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use looping for this problem:

```
function getnrout(rout)
    # assume we have at least one 0 in each row in column 1
    nrout = zeros(Int, size(rout, 1), size(rout, 2) - 1)
    for i in axes(rout, 1)
        section = 0
        for j in axes(rout, 2)
            v = rout[i,j]
            if v == 0
                section += 1
            else
                nrout[i, v] = section
            end
        end
    end
    return nrout
end
```

Comment: Im very grateful. but when the code was run. It had this error. I used `Int(axes(rout,1)` to solve that but it didn't work.
the Error is

    `MethodError: no method matching     start(::AxisArrays.Axis{:row,Base.OneTo{Int64}})[0m
Closest candidates are:
  start([91m::SimpleVector[39m) at essentials.jl:258
  start([91m::Base.MethodList[39m) at reflection.jl:560
  start([91m::ExponentialBackOff[39m) at error.jl:107`

Comment: moreover, `using AxisArrays` is used because axes was not known. Is it the problem?

Comment: If you don't have `axes`, you might be using an older Julia version than Bogumił. I think it was `indices` before.

Comment: yes. It worked now. would you please say me which version of Julia is better to install that it doesn't have bugs? Thanks very much.

Comment: I would recommend using Julia 1.1. For sure it is best not to use Julia 0.6 or earlier as they are not maintained. instead of `axes(rout, 2)` you can also write `1:size(rout, 2)` - this is the same in normal cases (unless you are using matrices with non-standard axes).